# How to check if an object is attached to ObjectContext?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I need to attach EF object (previously detached) to a new ObjectContext. The problem is that I don't know if it was attached or loaded before. And if there is an object with the same key loaded to ObjectContext I get an exception when I try to attach. Is there a way to check if there is an object with a particular key already attached?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The state of objects inside an object context is managed by the [ObjectStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectstatemanager.aspx).

**from MSDN:**

```
int orderId = 43680;

using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    ObjectStateManager objectStateManager = context.ObjectStateManager;
    ObjectStateEntry stateEntry = null;

    var order = (from o in context.SalesOrderHeaders
                 where o.SalesOrderID == orderId
                 select o).First();

    // Attempts to retrieve ObjectStateEntry for the given EntityKey.
    bool isPresent = objectStateManager.TryGetObjectStateEntry(((IEntityWithKey)order).EntityKey, out stateEntry);
    if (isPresent)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The entity was found");
    }
}
```

Also see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456854.aspx

**from previous MSDN link:**

```
// The changes are tracked as they occur and the state of the object is Modified.
Console.WriteLine(context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(newItem).State);
```

.. I suppose that in your case this could be one of the cached item.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I have come to the same idea, now checking if it will work with POCO objects.